# Coordinator Layout and some other layouts not working after migration to androidX

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, android-coordinatorlayout, androidx

I recently migrated my project to androidX using Refactor. All the implementations were automatically changed to androidx.
But I am not able use support design layouts example: Coordinator Layout
It is only showing grey color on the whole preview.

I googled and tried some fixes like changing the taregtSKDversion but nothing really helped.
I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

This is build.gradle [app]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pratham.sitapuriya"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    }

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.marlonlom:timeago:4.0.1'

}
```

I tried to use Coordinator Layout using

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
 // Other Childs
</<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And that wasn't working!
[Also all plugins are updated to latest version]
Please help..

**UPDATE**
After adding

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

The layout was working and gradle was build without any error.
But still when I run the app then it crashed giving this error

```
06-24 12:11:34.212 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
06-24 12:11:34.216 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
06-24 12:11:34.228 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
06-24 12:11:34.229 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
06-24 12:11:34.239 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
06-24 12:11:37.983 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.unwrapBackgroundDrawable
06-24 12:11:37.989 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.unwrapStrokeDrawable
06-24 12:11:37.992 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.setRippleColor
06-24 12:11:38.022 18074-18074/com.pratham.sitapuriya E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pratham.sitapuriya, PID: 18074
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pratham.sitapuriya/com.pratham.sitapuriya.AccountActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2433)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2484)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5486)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.pratham.sitapuriya.AppunctionsKt.beautifyLayout(appunctions.kt:76)
        at com.pratham.sitapuriya.AccountActivity.onCreate(AccountActivity.kt:14)
```

As My app was working without any errors before migration i guess these errors are due to androidx. Please figure it out. Thanks

Comment: use `material:material:1.0.0` & `appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` & remove multiple `com.google.android.material:material`

Comment: Yes ```android.useAndroidX = true``` that is already added

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I changed that lines and even removed extra ```com.google.android.material:material``` but nothing worked.

Comment: whats your error log saying

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya When I restarted the android studio and then rebuilded the gradle then the layouts started working perfectly. Post your comment as the answer so that i can mark it.  But still my app is crashing please help it out see the updated question. Thanks

Comment: Well. Ok. You can edit this question and provide us error log/logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with Stable version

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Then Clean-Rebuild-Run.

**FYI**

[**`NullPointerException`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value.

Comment: please also check the new probelm

Comment: But my application was working without errors before the migration

Comment: @PrathamVaidya check line number `(AccountActivity.kt:14)`

Comment: Ok I figured it out that was because of an exception caused by my function ```beautifyLayout()``` Thanks